# Not able to execute javascript inside page that's loaded via jQuery's ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Summary...**

I have a page that is loading other pages with ajax and they contain javascript. The javascript makes use of `document.ready` which doesn't work right when using code like this...

```
    $.ajax({

        type: 'get',
        url: 'layouts/' + layout + '.php',
        success: function(data){ 

            $('.swap').fadeOut('slow', function(){ // container

                $(this).delay(100).fadeIn().html(data);

            });

        }

    });
```

It doesn't work right in the sense that the javascript is running too fast.

What's the best way to load pages that make use of `document.ready` or code like it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use ajax to load a page, the javascript in that page will typically not be executed.  You can use jQuerys `load()` method to load the page in and then execute the scripts.

In your template page, add a `<div>` to hold the actual contents of the page like so:

```
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In your "control panel" page, have a container `<div>` as well:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="bxslider.js"></script>
```

You could then call your code in this manner

```
$(function(){

  var layout = 'layoutpage1';

  // this loads the contents of the #container div in layout page
  // into #container div on CP page.
  $('#container').load( '/layouts/' + layout + '.php #container', function() {
    initSlider();  // initialize the slider we just loaded
  });

  function initSlider() {
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            pager: false,
            controls: false,
            auto: true,
            mode: 'fade',
            speed: 1500
    });
  }

  // if there is already a slider on the page we can initialize it here
  // just remove comment
  // initSlider();
});
```

Comment: I didn't realize the fix would have been so easy. When I used `load` instead of `get` the javascript executes just fine. I didn't even have to worry about initializing the slider again...it just worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can add all your scripts in your main html file before body and try to initiate their functionality in the pages your are calling with ajax.

```
<div>

<ul class="slider">
    <li><img /></li>
    <li><img /></li>
</ul>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     //slider.init(); start slider 
  })
</script>
```

Comment: The code you are showing is the same thing I have, except I'm just linking to the script instead of putting it inside the page. I tried both methods and neither work when doing the ajax call. The weird thing is if I were to throw an `alert('test')` inside that script on the page...it executes on the ajax call, which goes against everything I've read...so I'm confused.

Comment: Well  linking the script inside the page means it calls the whole script each time you call this page. You just want to initiate something, so its better only to call the function. 
And adding document ready its always a good practice because most of the times you need everything to be ready to execute the script.

Comment: @idioteque `document.ready` doesn't help in ajax loaded page, the event occured a long time ago so it will fire immediately

Comment: The plugin will only work if inside `document.ready`...does that change anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `load()` method the scripts will execute. Note however that *document.ready* has already occurred in main page so scripts need to be after the html they reference.

Alternatively you can use `$.getScript()` in success callback

```
$('.swap').fadeOut(function(){
     $(this).load('layouts/' + layout + '.php', function(){
        $(this).fadeIn()
     });
})
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it doesn't work. In addition to what I wrote, if I were to remove the script from the page and make the call...I see my slider, all broken of course because of the lack of script, but if included...my images are gone, as if it's partially loaded, but not working completely. Bizarre.

Comment: are errors thrown? What's in the slider.js? Almost sounds like a plugin file is missing or something

Comment: No errors are thrown and the slider actually requires 2 files. There is one in the header that creates the jquery plugin, and the other one I'm having the issue with...the one that initializes the slider. I'm using http://bxslider.com/

Comment: I added links to my original post with actual code demonstrating the issue.

Comment: link above seems to work fine for me in Firefox when I clcik next. Make sure your broswer isn't caching

Comment: Are you sure? /lobby is what it looks like, with a slider, and if you click on 'next' to go to layout 2, which is what you saw on /lobby, the slider is no longer there because the script on layout 2 doesn't initialize the slider anymore.

Comment: yes... the `create page looks different than lobby on page load...then after click next looks the same and images are switching

Comment: What the heck? It doesn't work for me in Chrome nor Firefox, even with cache cleared. To be clear `/lobby` is showing layout 2. If you access layout 2 thru `/create` you will see the image slider is missing...or should be. I wonder how it's working for you...

Answer (score 0):

I'm spotting something dead simple here, otherwise i'm being dead simple....

" $('.swap').fadeOut('slow', function(){"

You have no class labelled swap in the HTML?

Comment: I do have that class because my navigation between layouts works just fine, but if loading a layout that has scripts...that's when I can see the failure.

Comment: Yeah I noticed i was the one being simple and had misread the question, thats why I deleted,undeleted again since you were quick to respond :)

Now I understand what's going on i'll attempt to come up with a more useful thing to say.

Comment: It's ok, I appreciate the effort regardless. I added links to my original post with actual code demonstrating the issue.

Comment: On your Ajax loaded page have an element...
    <script id="external_script" type="text/JavaScript"></script>


And then in the AJAX callback function try:
        document.getElementById('external_script').src = 'slider.js';

Comment: Or even try the good ol' document.write in the callback:


    document.write('<script src="', 'slider.js', '" type="text/JavaScript"><\/script>');

Comment: I tried both of those methods initially, and tried them again...nothing. The slider.js has to be inside the `document.ready`, so that might be where the issue is happening.

Comment: if you want to be absolutely sure that it's a 'ready' issue, set a 10second setTimeout(function(){<<PIN SCRIPT TO PAGE>> },10000); inside the Callback, which should guarantee all DOM elements loaded before the script fires. If it still fails then, you're looking at something other than a ready issue I reckon. Have you tested it in incognito/private mode to stop any kind of caching issues? Many of the methods listed here should work fine. Also I tested the links above, and sometimes the text scrolled in different layouts rather than an image, but things were moving.... ?

Comment: I think you're onto something, but I had to remove the script from the page being loaded in order for it to work, but it did work; however, because the script wasn't on the page...the images are all broken up before timer runs out, then it gets inserted and initializes and fixes everything. So I guess it's a matter of tweaking what I have, but this is a HUGE step in the right direction, so thank you. I wish I could give you points because I'm on the right path now. By the way, using document.write rids my page of all my other code, so I ended up doing an insertAfter element on the page...

Comment: Good stuff. Hope you get it all sorted. How about if you did a 100ms delayed insertAfter in a document.ready on the Ajax'd page? Or even without the timer from there... Yeah I didn't test any of the suggestions so missed that document.write heh. 

Good Luck!